# Can't place admob ads correctly

Tags: java, android, admob

I am learning to modify an Android app Source Code I bought online.there are already AdMob ads on some layouts but I want to add them to another layout.what I did was copy the needed code bits in relevant files.
this is the modified `fragment_category.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    tools:context=".CategoryFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container_body" >


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/container_admob"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_items"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

modified `CategoryFragment.java` file.only relevant bit( [full CategoryFragment.java file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxqhM-jr576ebUFkdjZ6ZEtjNHc) )

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements Constants, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private static final String STATE_LIST = "State Adapter Data";

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    TextView mMessage;
    LinearLayout mContainerAdmob;

    SwipeRefreshLayout mItemsContainer;

    private ArrayList<Item> itemsList;
    private FeedListAdapter itemsAdapter;

    private int categoryId = 0;

    private int itemId = 0;
    private int arrayLength = 0;
    private Boolean loadingMore = false;
    private Boolean viewMore = false;
    private Boolean restore = false;

    private String title = "";

    int pastVisiblesItems = 0, visibleItemCount = 0, totalItemCount = 0;

    public CategoryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContainerAdmob = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_admob);

        if (App.getInstance().getAdmob() == ADMOB_ENABLED) {

            mContainerAdmob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
```

in the .java file `findViewById` is in Red[error -  Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)  ]  fragment_java.xml file not is not showing any errors

working files

1. [activity_main.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxqhM-jr576eQVdMWWg0d2lwTms)
2. [MainActivity.java](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxqhM-jr576ed1ZLVUR6SVdzNlk)

what I added,

in fragment_category.xml

`xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
and

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/container_admob"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

in CategoryFragment.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

`LinearLayout mContainerAdmob;`

and

```
mContainerAdmob = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_admob);

        if (App.getInstance().getAdmob() == ADMOB_ENABLED) {

            mContainerAdmob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
```

if all this is too messy please suggest me a way to do this.I tried tutorials but each of them have different codes

Comment: You don't know how to use findViewById in a Fragment? That's been asked and answered many times

Comment: I don't really know......I will search for it.but if the other layout works,then why not this?

Comment: The Activity layout? It works because it's in an Activity, where findViewById is a method of the Activity class. You can't  just replace `extends Activity` with `extends Fragment` and have things working. For example, `fragment_category` doesn't seem to be really used in your question here

Answer (score 0):

> only relevant bit

You cut out onCreateView. Thats the method where you must use `rootView.findViewById` to get the adview and `mContainerAdmob`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement the methods of activity in a fragment. You have to use onCreateview() method of the fragment and inflate its layout and then can call the findViewById ();

The best way to implement

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, 
container, false);
AdView mAdView =
(AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
}
```

In this way, the rootView can be used for each id defined in the xml layout.

Hope this helps.